# How to check if a radiobutton is checked in a radio group

Tags: java, radio-button

I want to turn off the music when rbtOff is clicked. I tried this code but it didn't work - it still kept playing the music after I clicked off button.

BGM.java

```java
RadioButton rbtOn, rbtOff;
MediaPlayer bgm;
    ......

bgm = MediaPlayer.create(BGM.this, R.raw.ny);
    bgm.setLooping(true);
    bgmstart();
    //bgmStop();*/
}

public void bgmstart() {
    RadioButton rbtOn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtOn);
    RadioButton rbtOff = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtOff);
    if (rbtOff.isChecked())
    {
        bgm.release();
        bgm = null;
    }
    else if (rbtOn.isChecked())
    {
        bgm.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `bgm.stop();` and then `bgm.release();`